# A simple JS function issue -> Creating a function that will return only even numbers

Tags: javascript, function, numbers

I am learning JS using open sources and I tried to challenge myself by creating a function that will pull only the even numbers from the given array and return it in a new array that will only contain even numbers.

For example: evensOnly([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) should return only [2,4,6,8,10];

I have implemented below JS function but it is not giving the correct solution, when I run it on the console, it is saying undefined.

Can someone check and see what I did wrong?

```
function evensOnly(arr){

    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        let check = arr[i]%2;
        let evensArray;
        if (check === 0){
            evensArray.push();
        return evensArray;

        }

    }

}
evensOnly([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *evensArray* should be defined before the loop.
- You need to actually
  push the value of *arr[i]* into evensArray.
- You also need to return a
  value (in this case, evensArray) **after** the *for* loop has
  completed.

```js
function evensOnly(arr){
    let evensArray = [];
    for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        let check = arr[i]%2;
        if (check === 0){
            evensArray.push(arr[i]);
        }

    }
    return evensArray;

}
alert(evensOnly([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
```